# upsertGraph update rows based on different column than 'id'

Tags: javascript, node.js, objection.js

I have a products table with `id` and `supplier_id` columns.

How do I make `upsertGraph` update rows based on `supplier_id` instead of `id` when I fetch products from supplier?

Now `upsertGraph` only uses insert because there is no `id` property present.

**EDIT**

I fetch product lists from several different suppliers containing `id`, `name`, `price`

I store products in my database with `id`, `name`, `price` and `supplier_id`

Therefor I'm trying to make `upsertGraph` update/insert based on supplier_id, to update products based on supplier_id instead of id.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want to update based on the `supplier_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nope.**

Well what you want is not possible with `upsertGraph` as the official docs states

> By default upsertGraph method updates the objects that have an id,
>   inserts objects that don't have an id and deletes all objects that are
>   not present. This functionality can be modified in many ways by
>   providing UpsertGraphOptions object as the second argument.

REF: https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#graph-upserts

Its mentioned that default functionality can be modified but modifying the search based on different column than `id` is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Didnt try before but I think you could use [idColumn](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-properties.html#static-idcolumn):

```
class Supplier extends Model {
  static get idColumn() {
    return 'supplier_id';
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a hasManyRelation on products table to product_images 

When I tried changing idColumn() to return supplier_id, it stopped inserting relations correctly. (product_id was missing from product_images table)

Answer (score 0):

I had probably a similar issue from what I understand.

I have a `shipping` and a `shipping_address` table where the related table (shipping_address) carried the parent's id as `shipping_id`. However the shipping address row was inserted when upserting graph, but the shipping_id was not set and resulted in null.

In my relationMappings I had to explicitly change the relation to `HadOneRelation` from `BelongsToOneRelation`. From what I understand the relation direction is key here (which table carries the related id).

[See docs here...](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/relations.html#examples)

```js
    shippingAddress: {
      relation: Base.HasOneRelation, // <---- relation type
      modelClass: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ShippingRecipientAddress'),
      join: {
        from: 'shippings.id',
        to: 'shipping_recipient_address.shipping_id',
      },
    }
```